# Scrape tables from windguru

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to scrape tables from [www.windguru.com](http://www.windguru.com) but I can't find the table using BeautifulSoup.

Can anyone please help me with this? Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.windguru.cz/archive.php?id_spot=49308&id_model=3&date_from=2012-01-01&date_to=2012-12-31"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find('table', class_='forecast daily-archive')
```

Comment: must create a session with an account credentials and work with that one

Comment: I don't understand! Is that an answer for my question?

Comment: Yes that's part of the answer. The site requires a login, so you'll need to register and then create a session/post your credentials to the site.

Comment: I was connected with my email when i did the web scrapping. Do I need to have a PRO account?

Comment: browser cookies are different from the requests package cookies, see requests Sessions documentation

Answer (score -1):

When you are using BeautifulSoup and requests libraries to make a call to get data, it does not have your credentials of login, it's just like you have not logged in and tried to view the table, which is not allowed as I opened the webpage to see the table.

You can use selenium which will open a browser and then enter your login credentials and after that, you can continue to **scrape** using BeautifulSoup or try to create a session with requests library and **scrape** data.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish.